# How QSortFilterProxyModel works

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a window with `QListView` (left) and `QTableView` (right).
Both Views share the same data model.

`QListView` lists the dictionary keys such as 'Animals','Fish' and 'Birds'. When a left-side view's 'Animals' item is clicked a right-side view should display: a first column: 'Bison', a second column: 'Panther' and third: 'Elephant'.

To address this goal there was `QSortFilterProxyModel` assigned to right-side `QTableView` to filter its context. 
Every mouse click performed on a left-side QListView triggers `onClick()` function. This function checks what the left-side view's current item is. Then it queries the name of the key and a key's corresponding value from `self.modelDict` dictionary.

Here is a window screenshot:
[image]

Apparently the code doesn't do what it is supposed to. `QSortFilterProxyModel` does indeed display a correct "item"... so both views are in sync. That's good. But the right-side-table view is displaying the same key name in every column: "Animals","Animals","Animals". While the goal once again is to display the list of the animals themselves taken from a dictionary received from `.data()` method:

```
value=self.dataModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole)
```

where value is a dictionary such as:

```
{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'}
```

Please advise.

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class DataModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.modelDict={}    
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: return self.items[index.row()]
        if role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole: return self.modelDict.get(str(index.data().toString()))

    def addItem(self, itemName=None, column=0):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()+1
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, column)
        if not itemName:            itemName='Item %s'%self.rowCount()
        self.items.append(itemName)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.addItem(key) 

class ProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.dataModel=DataModel()
        self.dataModel.modelDict=elements
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 

        self.proxyModel=ProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)    
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.dataModel)

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick)          
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView() 
        self.viewB.setModel(self.proxyModel)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()

    def onClick(self):
        index=self.viewA.currentIndex()
        key=self.dataModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)  
        value=self.dataModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole)        
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp('%s'%key)
        print 'onClick(): key: %s'%type('%s'%key)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: QSortFilterModel is intended for selecting a subset of the same items from the model - you should not be surprised that you have the same words appearing in both views.

Comment: Located pretty good pyside-example: site:https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/raw/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024:examples/itemviews/basicsortfiltermodel.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayRole` should return different data for different rows.
Accodring to your code:

If `data` is called with `index(1,0)` it returns `Animals`.
If `data` is called with `index(1,1)` it returns `Animals`.
If `data` is called with `index(1,2)` it returns `Animals`.

Instead it should be

If `data` is called with `index(1,0)` it returns `Animals`.
If `data` is called with `index(1,1)` it returns `Bison`.
If `data` is called with `index(1,2)` it returns `Panther`.
If `data` is called with `index(1,3)` it returns `Elephant`.
Totally 4 columns.

To hide the first column which is a group name from the table view use `hideColumn(0)`.

ps. `ItemDataRole` is a enum name not a value.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize all the "work" needs to be done inside of scope of `DataModel.data` method (filling the model with indexes). I thought I would have to tweak `ProxyModel` to sort things out. What could be potentially bothering is that the indexe's row and column numbers need to be kept in sync with the data variable structure (here  `self.modelDict`). I'm also not sure if designing a model for multiple view widgets is a good idea.... Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. When designing model-view it's a common work to sync model data (row count, column count, text...) with a data storage. Usually it's also made using signals-slots. If you want to keep data in the model you should avoid changing the data outside the model. When the data is changed don't forget to `emit dataChanged` when a cell text is changed, `rowsAboutToBeInserted`, `rowsInserted` when adding rows, `rowsAboutToBeRemoved`, `rowsRemoved` when removing rows.

Comment: I did read briefly on `self.emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"),index,index)` used in `model.setData()`. But what is a reserved purpose of `rowsAboutToBeInserted, rowsInserted, rowsAboutToBeRemoved, rowsRemoved` slots? Why the `self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, column); self.items.append(itemName);self.endInsertRows()` can't be used solely and used in every situation when row is added?

Comment: Yes, they could. When you call `beginInsertRows` it emits signal `rowsAboutToBeInserted` etc.

Comment: What "happens" when `rowsAboutToBeInserted `is triggered? Same for `rowsInserted`... what happens after?

Comment: First of all, the model stores what operation are you going to perform to invalidate all `QPersistentModelIndex`. Also it emits signal which is accepted by a view. The view stores current cursor position and so on. So it is very important to call these methods `begin...`, `end...` to maintain consistency of data.

Comment: Hmmm...I see. Thanks a lot! Just when I thought I've nailed this subject down... ! :)